# Finding indices of max value in swift array

Tags: arrays, swift

I have 2 arrays. One for players and one for scores. e.g.

```
var players = ["Bill", "Bob", "Sam", "Dave"]
var scores = [10,15,12,15]
```

I can find the index of the (first) max score (and the winner's name) by using:

```
let highScore = scores.max()
let winningPlayerIndex = scores.index(of: highScore!)
let winningPlayer = players[winningPlayerIndex!]
```

This works fine if there is only one player with the highest score but how would I return multiple indices (i.e. 1 and 3 in this example) for all values that are equal to the max value? I need the indices to then map back to the players array to pull out the names of all the players with the highest score. Or is there a better way to do all of this?

Comment: You should make a `struct` for both the player name and score – then just have a single array of that.

Comment: Thanks @Hamish - it looks like structs are the way to go in this example. I am going to move this whole thing over to coredata/entities at some point but just trying to figure out some of the functionality first

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is to use custom `class` or `structure` and make array of it then find max score and after that filter your array with max score.

```
struct Player {
    let name: String
    let score: Int
}
```

Now create array of this Player `structure`

```
var players = [Player(name: "Bill", score: 10), Player(name: "Bob", score: 15), Player(name: "Sam", score: 12), Player(name: "Dave", score: 15)]

let maxScore = players.max(by: { $0.0.score < $0.1.score })?.score ?? 0
```

To get the array of player with max core use filter on array like this.

```
let allPlayerWithMaxScore = players.filter { $0.score == maxScore }
```

To get the array of index for player having high score use filter on array like this.

```
let indexForPlayerWithMaxScore = players.indices.filter { players[$0].score == maxScore }
print(indexForPlayerWithMaxScore) //[1, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks @Nirav - that does exactly what I need it to do. How does the maxScore function work? I can't quite follow it (am quite new to this!) and the syntax/structure is different to what xcode was presenting me with as i typed it in.

Comment: @mallowman Welcome mate :) What we have used is `max(by:)` you can get more details about it here https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2294243-max

Comment: Nice one. Cheers.

Comment: You could also say `players.lazy.map{ $0.score }.max()` to get the max score :)

Answer (score 16):

The accepted answer doesn't generalize to comparing computed values on the elements.  The simplest and most efficient way to get the min/max value and index is to enumerate the list and work with the tuples (offset, element) instead:

```
struct Player {
    let name: String
    let stats: [Double]
}

let found = players.enumerated().max(by: { (a, b) in
   battingAvg(a.element.stats) < battingAvg(b.element.stats)
})

print(found.element.name, found.offset)  // "Joe", 42
```

In general you shouldn't rely on comparing floating point values by equality and even where you can, if the computation is expensive you don't want to repeat it to find the item in the list.

Comment: what is battingAvg() ...? is it a custom method ?

Comment: Yes, that was just an example of an arbitrary, computed value. (It's a U.S. baseball thing).

Answer (score 7):

To answer just the question in the title -- find the index of the max value in a (single) array:

```
extension Array where Element: Comparable {
   var indexOfMax: Index? {
      guard var maxValue = self.first else { return nil }
      var maxIndex = 0

      for (index, value) in self.enumerated() {
         if value > maxValue {
            maxValue = value
            maxIndex = index
         }
     }

     return maxIndex
   }
}
```

The extension returns nil if the array is empty. Else, it starts by assuming the first value is the max, iterates over all values, updates the index and value to any larger values found, and finally returns the result.

Comment: What about: `a.indices.max { a[$0] < a[$1] }` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have 2 arrays and need to find max score from first one in order to pull the name from second one, then I would recommend you to convert both arrays into one using `zip` high order func and retrieve the max value from there.

So having your data it will look like this:

```swift
let players = ["Bill", "Bob", "Sam", "Dave"]
let scores = [10,15,12,15]

let data = zip(players, scores)

// max score
let maxResult = data.max(by: ({ $0.1 < $1.1 }))?.1 ?? 0
// outputs 15

// leaders
let leaders = data.filter { $0.1 >= maxResult }.map { "\($0.0) - \($0.1)" }
// outputs ["Bob - 15", "Dave - 15"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can zip the collection indices with its elements and get the minimum value using collection min method and pass a predicate to compare the elements. Get the result and extract the index of the tuple:

```
let numbers = [2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1]
let minIndex = zip(numbers.indices, numbers).min(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })?.0  // 5
let maxIndex = zip(numbers.indices, numbers).max(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })?.0  // 1
```

---

As an extension where the elements are comparable:

```
extension Collection where Element: Comparable {
    func firstIndexOfMaxElement() -> Index? {
        zip(indices, self).max(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })?.0
    }
    func firstIndexOfMinElement() -> Index? {
        zip(indices, self).min(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })?.0
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
numbers.firstIndexOfMinElement()  // 5
```

---

---

If you need to find the maximum or minimum properties:

```
extension Collection {
    func firstIndexOfMaxElement<T: Comparable>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T) -> Index? {
        zip(indices, self).max(by: { predicate($0.1) < predicate($1.1) })?.0
    }
    func firstIndexOfMinElement<T: Comparable>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T) -> Index? {
        zip(indices, self).min(by: { predicate($0.1) < predicate($1.1) })?.0
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
struct Product {
    let price: Int
}

let products: [Product] = [.init(price: 2),
                           .init(price: 4),
                           .init(price: 4),
                           .init(price: 2),
                           .init(price: 3),
                           .init(price: 1),]

let minPrice = products.firstIndexOfMinElement(\.price)    // 5
```

---

To return the maximum and minimum elements and their indices:

```
extension Collection where Element: Comparable {
    func maxElementAndIndices() -> (indices: [Index], element: Element)? {
        guard let maxValue = self.max() else { return nil }
        return (indices.filter { self[$0] == maxValue }, maxValue)
    }
    func minElementAndIndices() -> (indices: [Index], element: Element)? {
        guard let minValue = self.min() else { return nil }
        return (indices.filter { self[$0] == minValue }, minValue)
    }
}
```

---

And the corresponding methods to custom structures/classes:

```
extension Collection {
    func maxElementsAndIndices<T: Comparable>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T) -> [(index: Index, element: Element)]  {
        guard let maxValue = self.max(by:{ predicate($0) < predicate($1)}) else { return [] }
        return zip(indices, self).filter { predicate(self[$0.0]) == predicate(maxValue) }
    }
    func minElementsAndIndices<T: Comparable>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T) -> [(index: Index, element: Element)] {
        guard let minValue = self.min(by:{ predicate($0) < predicate($1)}) else { return [] }
        return zip(indices, self).filter { predicate(self[$0.0]) == predicate(minValue) }
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let maxNumbers = numbers.maxElementAndIndices()  // ([1, 2], element 4)
let minNumbers =  numbers.minElementAndIndices()  // ([5], element 1)

let maxPriceIndices = products.maxElementsAndIndices(\.price)    // [(index: 1, element: Product(price: 4)), (index: 2, element: Product(price: 4))]
let minPriceIndices = products.minElementsAndIndices(\.price)    // [(index: 5, element: __lldb_expr_22.Product(price: 1))]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to solve your problem, you can solve this by saving the indices of scores.max() and iterate through the players list, and also using then zip function:

```
var max_score = scores.max()
var players_and_score = zip(players, scores)
for player in players_and_score{
    if player.1 == max_score{
       print(player.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should calculate `max()` first or this will have a terrible performance.

Comment: Thanks @Edison - that works and would do what I need. didn't know about the zip function.