# Find lowest value and its index number in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have the following array
 `var numbers = [2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1]`

The sequence is very important and I need to find the index of the lowest value.
So how can I find the lowest value index? I need to be able to call numbers[lowestValueIndex] and get the correct value

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It might be best if you edit the question to show us what you tried. We're not here to solve your programming test for you. But we're happy to help if you show us your good faith attempt...

Comment: I have tried to sort the array and found the lowest value. However, if I do so, I can use ````numbers.first````, but my sequence is messed up.

Comment: @PeterHoldensgaard post your attempt

Comment: I don't see an exact match, but there's a lot of similar questions (it's similar for min or max) https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D++max+value+and+index

Comment: What if there are multiple correct answers? What do you want then?

Comment: @Alexander https://stackoverflow.com/a/66573960/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus That's a pretty good match. I think I also had an answer on this, but I can't find it now. I returned a tuple of the element and its index, I find that quite useful.

Comment: @LeoDabus I didn't downvote, but probably because it could be construed as not answering the question. The question was “get the index of the smallest value,” not “get the smallest value.” When a programming test question is worded like this, they're generally looking for something quite specific.

Comment: @Rob actually the question asks for the indices so it needs all indices instead of just the first one. Anyway I can also include all indices to my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always think it gives a cleaner call site to extend the array in this type of scenario.

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
   func lowest() -> (value: Element, positions:[Index])? {
      guard !isEmpty else {return nil }  //you may wish to throw an error rather than return nil
      return indices.reduce( (value: Element.max, positions: [Index]() ) ) {
         switch self[$1] {
            case let x where x < $0.value: return (value: self[$1], positions:[$1])
            case let x where x > $0.value: return $0
            default: return ($0.value, $0.positions + [$1])
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The switch statements can be simplified using an _ or pattern matching, but I feel this more verbose approach is easier to understand.  Throwing an error or returning a Result may be nicer way of dealing with an empty array than an optional return type, but would add bloat to the answer and can be added later by the OP if preferred.

```
[2,3,6,1,7,3,1,6,7].lowest() // (value: 1, positions: [3, 6])

[2,3,6,6,7,3,1,6,7].lowest() // (value: 1, positions: [6])

[Int]().lowest() // nil
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`min(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298201-min) array method; The trick is to operate on the array's `indices` property so that you can return the relevant index:

```
func minIndex(someArray: [Int]) -> Int? {
    return someArray.indices.min { someArray[$0] < someArray[$1] }
}
```

The function will return `nil` in the case where the array is empty.

For simplicity I have shown this as a function.  You could, of course, implement this as an extension on `Array` if you desired.

Comment: Why not just `[2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1].enumerated().min { $0.element < $1.element }` instead of the indexing?

Comment: You could do that.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers handle what to do if you only need one value. Otherwise…

```swift
let numbers = [2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1]

// [(offset 5, element 1), (offset 6, element 1)]
numbers.min().map { min in
  numbers.enumerated().filter { $0.element == min }
}
```

---

And if you're going to need the array sorted for further usage, prefix is better than filter.

```swift
let sorted =
  [2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1]
  .enumerated()
  .sorted(by: \.element)

sorted.first.map { first in
  sorted.prefix { $0.element == first.element }
}
```

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  /// Sorted by a common `Comparable` value.
  func sorted<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    by comparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable
  ) rethrows -> [Element] {
    try sorted(by: comparable, <)
  }

  /// Sorted by a common `Comparable` value, and sorting closure.
  func sorted<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    by comparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable,
    _ areInIncreasingOrder: (Comparable, Comparable) throws -> Bool
  ) rethrows -> [Element] {
    try sorted {
      try areInIncreasingOrder(comparable($0), comparable($1))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, `(<)` doesn't actually work, because you'd need to put `try` in front of all the calls. Overloading is the only way around that.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define the behavior of repetitive value in the input array.
Once that is done, try this:

```
  func returnLowestValueIndex(array: [Int]) -> Int? {
      guard !array.isEmpty else { return nil }
  
      var lowestValueIndex: Int = 0
      for (index, value) in array.enumerated() {
      if value < array[lowestValueIndex] {
         lowestValueIndex = index
      }
  
    return lowestValueIndex
  }

  var numbers = [2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 10]
  returnLowestValueIndex(array: numbers)
```